# JQuery Ajax communication with soap web service needs authentication

Tags: web-services, jquery, authentication, soap

To access to the web service, the request needs authentification with a username and a password, how to add them to my code:

```
function sendReq()
{    var wsUrl = "*******";
    var soapRequest ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
  '<soap:Body>'+
    '<UpdateImage xmlns="*******">'+
      '<urlSite>*********</urlSite>'+
      '<iListName>{*****}</iListName>'+
      '<iUpdateMode>****</iUpdateMode>'+
      '<iMetaData><Fields><Field Name="Title" >'+my_var1+'</Field></Fields></iMetaData>'+
      '<iAttachments><Attachments><Attachment Name="Nom du fichier 1">'+my_var2+'</Attachment></Attachments></iAttachments>'+
      '<iOverWrite>*****</iOverWrite>'+
    '</UpdateImage>'+
  '</soap:Body>'+
'</soap:Envelope>';
   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: wsUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "****/UpdateImage");
    },                
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            success: processSuccess,
            error: processError
        });
```

return false;

Comment: the authentication is required in the SOAP header block. Do you have a sample request ?

Comment: I have tried to add  
beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('username', 'password')); }. With:  
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}
but nothing happen

Comment: thats the AJAX authorization and not SOAP. please see sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client

Comment: using xmlhttpRequest I have added them like this `xmlhttp.open("POST", wsUrl, true,"username","password");` but I want to work with jquery.Ajax